# Parse a string of commas and numbers

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, validation

I found a nice jQuery plugin. It sends data to the php server as `1202,39,2393,29,1,39`

I want to get that data from the post, i know how to do this.

My idea is to put `1202,39,2393,29,1,39` in a string. then some how loop through it.

So i would put in `$string = '1202,39,2393,29,1,39';`
The output would be something like

```
 1202<br>
    39<br>
    2393<br>
    29<br>
    1<br>
    39<br>
```

For each ID in the loop i would check if its a valid id. I know how to check in MySql if something exists. The part i'm not sure on is getting each id in a loop from the string and then doing something with it. This seems hard to explain, i hope i'm clear.

Comment: You can simply use explode function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php to split it by `,`

Comment: Added `mysql` tag because it is an important factor in this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You should not run SQL queries in a loop**, so I'd say you should not `explode()` it at all (what others suggested). This is a very bad practice, because if you have **20 IDs**, it will mean **20 database calls**, which is very very inefficient. Database calls should be minimized if possible because they are expensive.

I'd run a query which returns those IDs that are in the database.

Your query would be something like

```
 select id from table where id in (YOUR_STRING_ESCAPED)
```

Be sure to escape your `$string` first for example with `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

The IDs that are returned from your query are the ones that can be safely outputted.

- [MySQL IN()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Comment: select id from accounts where id in 2,8,9,10 gives #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2,8,9,10 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: @Keverw Note the `()` around the string.

Comment: Oh. I was thinking you just put that in to show a variable. Thanks! My app will use both this method and loop method. One is to check when saving for a draft, other one will be used to insert in to each users mailbox.

Comment: @Keverw If by `insert in to each users mailbox` you mean SQL `INSERT` calls, you should not invoke those from a loop either. `INSERT` supports inserting multiple records with one call.

Answer (score 2):

To break the string up into separate pieces, use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$string = '1202,39,2393,29,1,39'; 
$list = explode(",", $string);
```

You could then do whatever you want with the array, e.g.

```
foreach ($list as $item)
{
    print $item."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode()` first to create an array:

```
$string = '1202,39,2393,29,1,39';
$array= explode(",", $string);
```

Then use a `foreach` loop to do your checks:

```
foreach ($array as &$value) {
    if($value == etc.....//perform your checks here.
}
```

Comment: That's the problem with the softball questions. I'm new at SO, and torn between answering lots of easy ones or a few hard ones. A few hours ago I wrote an elaborate answer for a problem and the question was deleted less than a minute before I posted. `*sob*`

Comment: This just seems to be a softball question... I was wondering everyone is suggesting running SQL queries in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '1202,39,2393,29,1,39';
$array = explode(',', $string);
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++) {
    $sql = "CHECK FOR VALID ID WHERE id=" . $array[$i];
}
```

This should get all of those id's for you to check via sql individually.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using PHP:

```
$string = '1202,39,2393,29,1,39';
$data = explode(",", $string);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); echo "</pre>"

// Outputs:
// Array
// (
//     [0] => 1202
//     [1] => 39
//     [2] => 2393
//     [3] => 29
//     [4] => 1
//     [5] => 39
// )

// Then you can iterate through the array
foreach ($data AS $value) {
  // Validate the $value
}
```